# How to redistribute unique integer ids in a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, derby

**Consider this:**

- I have a database with 10 rows.
- Each row has a unique id (int) paired with some value e.g. name (varchar).
- These ids are incremented from 1 to 10.
- I delete 2 of the records - 2 and 8.
- I add 2 more records 11 and 12.

**Questions:**

- Is there a good way to redistribute unique ids in this database so it would go from 1 to 10 again ?
- Would this be considered bad practice ?

I ask this question, because after some use of this database: adding and deleting values the ids would differ significantly.

Comment: Specif an examle or an code

Comment: *Would this be considered bad practice ?* yes I consider this as a bad practice.

Comment: Do you have any reason to try and do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to just generate the row numbers you want at the time you actually query, something like this:

```
SET @rn = 0;

SELECT 
    (@rn:=@rn + 1) AS rn, name
FROM yourTable;
ORDER BY id;
```

Generally speaking, you should not be worrying about the auto increment values which MySQL is assigning.  MySQL will make sure that the values are unique without your intervention.

Comment: I think they way i was thinking about it is wrong. The unique identifier in a database shouldn't be used as a counter for objects. I think a better way would be to add a new variable e.g. row and use that instead. Do you agree ?

Comment: @rocispire Actually, I think my suggestion is a good one, because you might be able to rely on order, but not continuous values.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ID column to be primary key and an auto-increment as well, "resetting" is not really necessary because it will keep assigning unique IDs anyways.

If the thing that bothers you are the "gaps" among the existing values, then you might resort to "sort deletion", by employing the **is_deleted** column with bit/boolean values. Default value would be 0 (or b0), of course. In fact, soft-deleting is advised if there are some really important data that might be useful later on, especially if it involves possibility for payment-related entries where user can delete one of such entries either by omission or deliberately.

There is no simple way to employ the deletion where you simply remove one value and re-arrange the remaining IDs to retain the sequence. A workaround might be to do the following steps:

1. DELETE entry first. i.e. `delete from <table> where ID = _value`
2. INSERT INTO SELECT (without id column). please note that the table need to be identical in terms of columns and types in order for this query to work properly, so to speak... and you can also utilize temporary as the backup_table. i.e. `insert into <backup_table> select <coluum1, column2, ...> from <table>`
3. TRUNCATE your table, i.e. `truncate table <table>`
4. copy the values from the temp table back into the existing table. You can utilize the INSERT INTO SELECT once again, but make sure to drop the temp table in the end

Please note that I would NOT advise you to do this, mainly because most people utilize some sort of caching in their applications and they also utilize the specific ways to evaluate whether a specific object is the same. 
I.e. in Java, the equals() and hashCode() methods for POJOs are overriden and programmers generally rely on IDs to be permanent way of identifying a specific object. By utilizing the above method, you essentially break the whole concept and I would not advise you to change the object's autoincrement ID value for this reason, before anything else.

Essentially, what you want to do is simply an anti-pattern and will generally make common patterns and practices employed by experienced programmers into solutions that are prone to unexpected issues and/or failures... and this especially applies if/when advanced features are involved, such as employing this such anti-pattern into an application that utilizes galera cluster and/or application caching.